# Group and send all files to filetype folder

Tags: python, file-system, linux, shell

I have around ~2M of files in one folder, which I need to manage. So, I want to separate them in groups by their filetypes.

Example:

filenames

```
1.A, 2.A, 3.A, 2.B, 3.B, 4.B, 5.C, 6.C
```

My code:

```
import os
all_files = os.listdir(".")
filetypes = list(set([i.split(".")[-1] for i in all_files]))
for i in filetypes:
    os.system("mkdir -p %s"%i)
    os.system("mv *.%s %s"%(i, i))
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make this a bit more robust. You might have control over what is generated, but it won't hurt to make sure of a few things:

Filter out any non-files:

```
 all_files = (x for x in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(x))
```

You can iterate over a `set` just fine, no need to convert it back to a list. Further, `os` already has a `splitext` method that'll separate a filename into `(name, ext)`, and will give the `ext` as `''` if it doesn't exist (currently, your code will crash if there is no extension):

```
filetypes = set((os.path.splitext(f)[1] for f in all_files]))
```

There is also a `move` command in `shutil` that you could use instead of a call to `os.system()`, which is likely to be a lot faster (and safer). To generate the file names, you can use `glob`:

```
for ftype in filetypes[1:]:
    os.mkdir(ftype)
    for fname in glob.iglob('*.{0}'.format(ftype)):
        shutil.move(fname, ftype)
```

If these files are somewhat important, you might want to consider copying and then delete them instead of moving them directly.

Comment: Extension returned by `splitext` contains the period, so your syntax for `format` is wrong. Also there's an additional closing bracket in the `filetypes` declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid `os.system()` by all means. It wastes resources by creating 2 processes per invocation, and is vulnerable to various attacks (at least spell out full paths to the `mkdir` and `mv` utilities).

`os.mkdir()` provide all necessary functionality (don't forget to `catch OSError`). A combination of `os.link()` and `os.unlink()` emulates `mv` (they are only available on Unix - but you are calling `mv` anyway).

Comment: also worse: using `os.system("mv *.%s %s"%(i,i))` when there are filenames with spaces in them can cause catastrophic consequences since part of the filename can be interpreted as a shell command.